# WordPress multisite | ROOT redirects to SUBFOLDER

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem on my WordPress multisite. There's a WordPress installation on the root folder  (public_html) of my domain and it was working fine.

We had to install a second WordPress site in a subfolder (public_html/subfolder).

If I try to access example.com/subfolder, the second website works fine.

If I try to access example.com, it redirects to example.com/subfolder. I no longer can access the first website.

ROOT .HTACCESS

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

SUBFOLDER .HTACCESS

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subfolder/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Can someone explain how to prevent this redirect?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to delete (or rename) root .htacces.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you explained your logic behind it.